# Sending Array object in GTM

Tags: angular, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have three dimensions and one metric in Google Analytics, I am populating these with the help of google tag manager, where I had created a Tag which is executed on a certain event.

This is working fine till the time I am sending a single object

```
(<any>window).dataLayer.push({
      AgentEmail: 'bbj@gmail.com',
      AgentLocation: 'Delhi',
      AgentName: 'Agent0007',
      AgentCount: '100',
      event: 'agentInfo'
    });
```

but when I am trying to send an array object I am unable to do same i.e.  if suppose I want to send information of two agents it's saving only single info

```
  (<any>window).dataLayer.push({
      AgentEmail: 'z@gmail.com',
      AgentLocation: 'Delhi',
      AgentName: 'Agent0007',
      AgentCount: '100',
      event: 'agentInfo'
    },({
       'AgentEmail': 'z@gmail.com',
     'AgentLocation': 'Delhi',
     'AgentName': 'Agent0008',
      'AgentCount': '100',
     'event': 'agentInfo'
 });
```

Even I tried to create two separate object of data layer and try to send both object differently but that also dont work.

Can one please help what change need to be done in GTM Tags/variable and in front end to populate data Layer.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra parentheses boi "(" between your objects.

```
dataLayer.push({
      AgentEmail: 'z@gmail.com',
      AgentLocation: 'Delhi',
      AgentName: 'Agent0007',
      AgentCount: '100',
      event: 'agentInfo'
    },{ //here you need to remove the "("
       'AgentEmail': 'z@gmail.com',
     'AgentLocation': 'Delhi',
     'AgentName': 'Agent0008',
      'AgentCount': '100',
     'event': 'agentInfo'
 });
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry for delay reply stuck with something else. Meanwhile, even if I do as suggested by you, it's only pushing single element to GTM Tag. While in data layer it's showing two objects any idea how we can achieve same